# In "Conversation Learner" in "Train Dialog" could I add multiple "actions" as an answer to one "User Input"?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, conversationlearner

In "Conversation Learner" in "Train Dialog" could I add multiple "actions" as an answer to one "User Input"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out the resolution is in unchecking the "[Wait for Response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/labs/conversation-learner/tutorials/2-wait-vs-nonwait-actions)" checkbox when creating the answer (Action)

[image]

In such way your chatbot can send any ammount of replies until first of them with "Wait for Response" checked comes into action. This status is visible also in the "Train Dialog" as you can see on the image below.

[image]